# Find sibling control in Repeater

Tags: .net, vb.net, repeater, findcontrol

I have a `Repeater` structured something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListClaimTypes" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuContract" runat="server" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CommandName='<%# Eval("ClaimTypeID")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need to handle the file upload when `btnUpload` is clicked. I can access the control that triggered the subroutine with `sender`. How would I access `fuContract`?

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ClaimTypeID As Integer = sender.CommandName
    Dim fuContract As FileUpload = '??

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current method of Event handling you would cast the sender as a LinkButton, cast the parent as a RepeaterItem, and then use FindControl to find the FileUpload Control:

```
Dim fuContract As FileUpload = CType(CType(sender, LinkButton).Parent.FindControl("fuContract"), FileUpload)
```

I prefer handling these types of Events using the Repeater's ItemCommand Event though:

```
Private Sub rptListClaimTypes_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rptListClaimTypes.ItemCommand

    Dim fuContract As FileUpload = CType(e.Item.FindControl("fuContract"), FileUpload)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great. I did just work it out using a slightly long winded way `Dim btnUpload As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)` `Dim rpItem As RepeaterItem = TryCast(btnUpload.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)` `Dim fuContract As FileUpload = rpItem.FindControl("fuContract")` but your one-liner is much better. Many thanks.